# ReactJS with Sockets Nested JSON parsing data issue

Tags: json, reactjs, setstate

I have a JSON file that has a structure like this "data.json"

```
{
    "Object1": {
        "name": "1",
        "rank": "2"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "name": "3",
        "rank": "4"
    }
}
```

and in my React code, I have my data to set my react state. I want to pass Object2 to a different component, but I can't seem to differentiate the data.

```
// import packages
import React, { Component } from "react";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            data: null
        };
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

        // Binders
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.socket.on('send data', this.updateState);
    }

    updateState(result) {
        this.setState({
            data: result
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                {this.state.data}
            </p>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

When I try to reference something like this.state.data or this.state.data.Object1.name, it points to a null object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put a `console.log(this.state)` before `return` in your `render` method. What do you see in the second render?  Also, you can't render objects into the DOM directly. This does not work: `{this.state.data}`.

Comment: @devserkan i see the data in my blank home page and console. Why does this.state.data not work? It works, but not the way I am trying to get it to work. I am piping everything through a socket to update the app entirely at one time.

Comment: is it because it's not `Object1` but `Object11` ?

Comment: @azium it's simply a typo. That does not make a difference. https://gyazo.com/150dd6bd270513982357022d7dc73570

Comment: oh the error in your screenshot is different then what you said. it's not saying `Object1` is null, it's saying `data` is null. @devserkan answer is correct

Comment: I am just taking a blind guess, as your code above seems fine. But once you reference something like ` this.state.data.Object1.name` in your render function you will get initially an null error, because the socket has not yet returned any data. If this is the case you could do a null check at the beginning of your render function and make sure you actually have data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know so much about sockets but since you are setting the state after the first render, there isn't any data until `componentDidMount` finishes its job. So, you need conditional rendering.

```js
const data = {
  "Object1": {
    "name": "1",
      "rank": "2"
  },
  "Object2": {
    "name": "3",
      "rank": "4"
  }
};

const fakeRequest = () => new Promise( resolve => 
  setTimeout( () => resolve(data), 2000 )
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest().then( data => this.setState({data}));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {!this.state.data ? "No data yet, wait 2 seconds." : this.state.data.Object1.name }
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can't use `{this.state.data}` since a React child can't be object. You need to use the values of this object.

Comment: I see what the issue is now, but I am using a socket, this would work if I was grabbing from an API. Will try to mess around and see what I can do

Comment: So, the socket.on() is a callback, and I set the state through the callback from there. How can I let the setState to finish before rendering?? I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is the difference using a socket or getting the data from an API here? At some point, you get the data right? And it goes coming I presume, like a stream. So, conditional rendering should work. You can't let `setState` finish before the first render or pause the render in any way. Your component mounts and hits the first render before `componentDidMount`. This is why we use conditional rendering here.

Comment: Very true. I’ll have to try this out when I get home. I believe your answer is right. It logically makes sense, it’s just my implementation is wrong and I realize that now.