# ReactJS SocketIO setState to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, setstate

From my previous thread here [ReactJS with Sockets Nested JSON parsing data issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868837/reactjs-with-sockets-nested-json-parsing-data-issue), I am trying to figure out the best way to setState of my react component and have the state be of JSON

An example of my code would be here for the JSON:

```
{
    "Object1": {
        "name": "1",
        "rank": "2"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "name": "3",
        "rank": "4"
    }
}
```

In my React code, I am setting state as such.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.socket.on('send data', this.updateState);
}

updateState(result) {
    this.setState({
        data: result
    });
    this.toObj = JSON.parse(this.state.data);
}
```

What can I do to setState as a JSON object so I can readily use the data in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse it before the `setState` and refer to the state directly:

```
updateState(result) {
  const data = JSON.parse(result);
  this.setState({
    data
  });
}

render() {
  return (
     <ul>
       {this.state.data.map(obj => (
         <li><span>{obj.name}</span>: <span>{obj.rank}</span></li>
       )}
     </ul>
  )
}
```